# $TdS=dU$ for a system going a quasi-static process

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, entropy

I have a question regarding entropy:

The change in intropy for a **system** at constant composition with no other work than volume work is:

$T_sdS=dU +pdV$, were $T_s$ is the surrounding temperature, and $p$ is the system pressure

$T_sdS= dQ -p_sdV + pdV$

if the process is done in a quasi-static manner, p_s=p (because we are pretty close to equilibrium)

T_sdS=dQ (valid for a quasi-static process)

If the process is reversible,

TdS=dQ (in this case T is the system temperature)

What I dont understand is the following: in a quasi-static process we are very close to the equilibrium position, so the system temperature is always equal to the surrounding temperature because in the equilibrium

(for the composite system) dS=0=(1/T -1/T_s)dU + (p/T - p_s/T_s)dV

because dS must vanish for every dU and dV

1/T=1/T_S

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is, if T=T_s , then the expression for a quasi-static process is always the same that for a  then the expression for a quasi-static process is always the same that for a reversible process, and that is absurd because, every reversible process is quasi-static but not every quasi-static process y reversible.

Comment: Please provide what you consider a quasi-static process that is not reversible so that we can focus on the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment to @pwf stated that your question actually is

> My question is, if $T=T_s$ , then the expression for a quasi-static
> process is always the same .......as that for a reversible process,
> and that is absurd because, every reversible process is quasi-static
> but not every quasi-static process is reversible.

An example of a quasi-static process that is irreversible is one that involves mechanical friction. In such a case you can have $T_{sys}=T_{surr}$ at the system boundary because mechanical friction generates thermal energy (generates entropy) *within* the system.

So the change in entropy is

$$\Delta S=\frac{Q}{T}+σ$$

Where the term $\frac{Q}{T}$ is the entropy transferred at the system  boundary where $T=T_{sys}=T_{surr}$ and  $σ$ is the entropy generated within the system due to mechanical friction.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. you have been very helpfull!